# When Shiro integrates JWT, what Shiro filter should be extend?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, shiro

When I want to integrate JWT with Shiro, I need to write a filter extend Shiro's filter class
For example

> **AuthenticatingFilter**
>
> **BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter**
>
> **AccessControlFilter**

I don't know which filter I should choose to extend,I'd like to ask about their differences. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs: https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#default_filters
(sorry for the RTFM)

Basically, each filter will process the data of the request differently,

- `authcBasic` - will use basic auth `Authorization: Basic base64(username:password)`
- `authcBearer` - a bearer token: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`
- `authc` - an HTML form post
  There are a few other ones, but hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but I don't really agree with [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71756633/1549977) here. The docs won't tell you much about the specialities of a JWT.

JWTs work differently than other (Bearer) tokens: They need to be parsed BEFORE entering the Realm, because they usually contain  roles or other information. Traditional auth information on the other hand will be parsed later, using the Realm's CredentialsMatcher.

That said, you will need at least three classes:

- A JWT Realm (obviously)
- A JWT Filter (which verifies the JWT and extracts information as needed)
- ... as well as the Token class, as the SimpleAuthenticationToken does not hold enough information.

You will then need to add the new Filter to your shiro.ini's URL configuration and configure the realms.

You can see a full working example here: https://github.com/bmarwell/shiro-jwt-showcase. There's a full blog post explaining it: https://blog.bmarwell.de/2022/04/26/apache-shiro-jwt-authentication-jjwt.html

**Disclaimer:**
I am also on the Shiro team and I authored both the linked GH repo and the blog post.

Comment: Hi Benjamin,
Why should JWTs be parsed before the realm? To keep things simple I have an implementation that uses the default 'authcBearer'. For handling the JWTs I wrote a supporter that maps the bearer token to my custom token using [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples) which handles validation as well through jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwt)
I found a similar approach in the [Okta-Shiro-plugin](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-shiro-plugin/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/okta/shiro/realm/OktaResourceServerRealm.java). Any feedback on this approach?

Comment: it is generally recommended to parse tokens in a filter before hitting the Realm. This is because the filter provides a convenient and flexible point in the request-response cycle where the tokens (JWT or User/PW) can be extracted and validated. You can make sure only valid requests are passed to the realm. Also, you could already extact information and pass it to the realm via other means.

Comment: The same is done with base64 (basic) auth. The filter will look for valid tokens [ base64(user:pass)] before passing it to the realms.